# PHP AJAX login, is this method secure?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, authentication, security

I have just started PHP and MySQL and have created a login form and all works well! Now I am looking to add ajax and the first method I considered is using the jQuery $.post method. I am okay with the code and here is a quick idea of what I will be doing:

```
function login(){
    $.post('login.php', {
      username:form.username.value,
      password:form.password.value
    })
}
```

All I need to know is, is this secure and if not what method should I consider?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's as secure as any other method of form submission would be to the same URL.

Answer (score 1):

It is never secure to send passwords in plain text.  But if this is for a simple application then it would be fine.  But if this was for something like a banking application you would need to use a more secure transmission protocol such as SSL.

Comment: At the moment it is simply something I wanted to do so I could learn about it. I do lots of these things and never put them to use! I have tried to make it as secure as possible and only have a simple hosting account as I only ever use it for testing! Thanks for the response!