# Is this a secure method of hasing a password in Java

Tags: java, mysql, security, password-storage

I'm creating a hash from a given password in Java and storing that into a MySQL database.  I've read a lot about storing a salt in the database but there are a couple reasons I've chosen not to here.  There seems to be no way to completely hide a random salt specific to each user from *Hacker* and there's no way to hide that I have a hosted database and downloadable software.  Because this software is only used in house it has at most 20 users and *Hacker* is far more likely to stumble upon the database port than he is the software.  At least by generating the salt in the software instead of storing it in the database, he'll need to find the software to decompile and determine the salt/hash method.

Here's the mothod I'm using:

```java
public static byte[] getHash(String password) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException {

    MessageDigest digest = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-256");

    byte[] passBytes = password.getBytes();

    byte[] salt = digest.digest(passBytes);     

    byte[] digestable = new byte[passBytes.length + salt.length];

    System.arraycopy(passBytes, 0, digestable, 0, passBytes.length);
    System.arraycopy(salt, 0, digestable, passBytes.length, salt.length);

    return digest.digest(digestable);
}
```

EDIT:
[Precident for putting this here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12218887/is-this-a-secure-way-to-hash-a-password)

I see that I need to generate a random salt and I can store it now.

Comment: If you have working code, http://www.codereview.stackexchange.com may be the better place to ask this question

Comment: I would also recommend security.stackexchange.com for things related to security of algorithms.

Comment: The salt is not something that needs to be secret. See: http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/211/how-to-securely-hash-passwords

Comment: Even better explanation: http://security.blogoverflow.com/2013/09/about-secure-password-hashing/

Comment: I posted here because as you can see, there are already two other places that this *might* belong and I found precident: [Precident 1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3331431/php-ajax-login-is-this-method-secure) [Precident 2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3336636/php-ajax-login-is-this-method-secure?rq=1) [Precident 3](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3811302/is-this-a-secure-encryption-method) I found better precident that looks incredibly similar to my post (different langauge/method) with 7+ upvotes, that post was the reason I put it here.

Comment: How do you intend to ever check the password hash if you do *not* store your salt?

Comment: @Durandal My thinking was that the salt will always be generated the same way, but can't be guessed (i.e., using the username as the salt).

Comment: @Durandal Edited because I thought seeding the SecureRandom was giving me constant results.

Comment: @roundar - A salt which is derrived from the password itself, is not a salt at all, it is just a bit more complex hash function. The purpose of the salt will be negated, because you still can build 1 rainbow-table to get all passwords at once.

Comment: Others have told you that the salt is not supposed to be a secret.  If you follow the links they gave you, then you'll also know that it _is_ supposed to be _random_.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the only acceptable password hashing methods are bcrypt, scrypt, and PBKDF2.

SHA-256 is too fast. You want a slow hashing method, like the above.

If you main security threat is SQL injection, then you should pepper the passwords. This means HMAC-ing the password with a secret known by the web server, but not the database server. See https://blog.mozilla.org/webdev/2012/06/08/lets-talk-about-password-storage.

You should also deny user/password table access to your web server, and have a very simple stored procedure api for authentication.